# How can I align items of Toolbar to the right in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

How can I align the items of a toolbar to the right??
All alignment settings seem to not work.

I´m using the layout designer.

Please help

[image]

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="vmanager.ui.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
        prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<top>
    <ToolBar prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
        <items>
            <Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" text="_"/>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false"/>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="X" onAction="#close"/>
        </items>
    </ToolBar>
</top>
```

Comment: Are you using `Scene Builder` ?

Comment: Yes I am. I want to make a custom window with close, minimize and fullscreen button

Comment: You don't need to do that ! You need to create a Stage and it will automatically be handled by javafx.

Comment: But then it´s the default windows look

Comment: Yes, all the windows that open in an `OS` must follow some rules ! The alignment of these three items being one of them !

Comment: and thats why I created a toolbar and I now want to align those buttons right instead of the default left alignment

Comment: May be some code would help !

Answer (score 4):

This is doable with an `AnchorPane` instead of the toolbar:

```
<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <top>
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="50.0">
      <children>
        <Button layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" />
        <Button layoutY="15.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="70.0" />
        <Label layoutY="18.0" prefWidth="449.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="140.0" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

I also added the "window title" label. You can style the `AnchorPane` however you like later, if this achieves your desired layout behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot align Toolbar items to right in Scenebuilder. For this to achieve you have to do it programatically. Below is the sample code I use on top of a TableView

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    btnset.setMinWidth(toolbar.getWidth()/2);
    btnset.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    recnum.setMinWidth(toolbar.getWidth()/2);
    recnum.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
}
});
```

This can be done only after the ToolBar has been painted on the scene, hence using Platform.runlater.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if you used an `HBox` rather than a `Toolbar`? I know you don't get the look of the toolbar, but it is easy to float things to the right using a regular `Pane` with the Hgrow attribute set to ALWAYS as a spacer. Here (total hack), I put a `Toolbar` behind the HBox in a StackPane to let the look of it come through, but you could certainly do that better with css. Also, you will, or course, need id's on your buttons in order to work with them. I also didn't bring forward your embedded controller definition, so don't forget to include that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <StackPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <children>
            <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="_" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="O" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="X" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="6.0" left="6.0" right="6.0" top="6.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: See marked duplicate Ron, it's likely a better solution.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't know you could inject attributes into the FXML like that. Is there a way to add the HBox.hgrow attribute from within Scenebuilder? I just stuffed it into the code, and it (obviously) worked great.