# JavaFX right-justified MenuBar

Tags: javafx-2, menubar

In JavaFX, is there any way that I can either set a MenuBar to use a given layout or even change the MenuBar's MenuItem orientation directly? I'm looking for something similar to glue or an invisible area in Swing, because I need to put items on the right of a MenuBar.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I align items of Toolbar to the right in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096520/how-can-i-align-items-of-toolbar-to-the-right-in-javafx)

Comment: have you been able to solve it? you might want to check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698531/create-resizable-borders-for-empty-stage/31704685#31704685)